# Getting coordinates of mouse when in the browser chrome

Tags: javascript

I can retrieve the mouse coordinates just fine when actually on the web page document (event.clientX/Y), but as soon as the cursor creeps onto the browser chrome, coordinates stop being sent.

I highly doubt this is possible after researching it, but I thought I'd just throw it out there; Does anyone know of a way to retrieve the mouse coordinates when the cursor is over the browser chrome?

At the moment, I've had to resort to a hacky workaround, that predicts that the user is in that vicinity as A) their cursor was moving fast enough and the next movement would  theoretically be on the browser chrome and B) mouse movement events are no longer coming through.

This may be the closest I can get through JS alone, but if you have any ideas I'd be very grateful. Just to be clear, I mean the area show in the below image.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226299/capturing-mouse-position-outside-of-browser-window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events are fired for the document. `JavaScript` is meant for `DOM` manipulation and events outside of the document context are outside of this scope. Consider writing a browser plugin for such.