# How to change cursor without the need of mouse movement if window not focused

Tags: css, webkit, cursor

For some reason the cursor gets not changed if the window is not focused. While moving, the mouse it is updating correctly. This occurs at least in IE11 & Chrome, but not in FF.

Is there a way to fix/workaround that issue or is this maybe the expected behaviour?

Here some little test code:

```
var cursors = ['default','text','no-drop','progress','all-scroll'];
var cursor = 0;
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
setInterval(function(){
    cursor = (cursor +1 ) % cursors.length;
    body.innerText = cursors[cursor];
    body.style.cursor = cursors[cursor];
}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4DTpp/

Comment: it works fine with my chrome browser

Comment: also working in Firefox 29.0.1 on Windows 8.1

Comment: @frieder - sure you focused another window then put the mouse over the fiddle's canvas? Is then still changing while your mouse is not moved?

Comment: @Möhre you are right, my fault

Answer (score 0):

It is an expected behaviour.Because if browsers allow this, there will be a security issue as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8330255/458679).